# Table to JSON using node.js

Tags: html, json, node.js

I am trying to convert a table to JSON, to search for data easily, the URL is: http://www.tppcrpg.net/rarity.html

I found this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabletojson

I tried to use it like:

```
'use strict';

const tabletojson = require('tabletojson');

        tabletojson.convertUrl(
            'http://www.tppcrpg.net/rarity.html',
            { useFirstRowForHeadings: true },
            function(tablesAsJson) {
                console.log(tablesAsJson[1]);
            }
        );
```

However it returns undefined in the console, are there any alternative options or am I using the package wrong?

Comment: Do you want to convert this remote url?

Comment: Yes I want to get the data in JSON because I wouldn't know how to get data from a row in table format

Comment: is the tppcrg url is yours?

Comment: No it is not mine

Comment: Ok you are unable to access there data of third party api, but you want that data, so you are trying this am i correct?

Comment: I can acces the data using that URL but not in the format I want, here they have a documentation: http://wiki.tppc.info/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&meta=siteinfo&titles=Main%20Page&rvprop=user%7Ccomment&continue= but it does not say anything about the rarity endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are actually getting data, change the console.log

Your output have total one array only but you are putting tablesAsJson[1] in console, but array index starts with [0].

```
'use strict';

    const tabletojson = require('tabletojson');
    tabletojson.convertUrl(
        'http://www.tppcrpg.net/rarity.html',
        function(tablesAsJson) {
            console.log(tablesAsJson[0]);
        }
    );
```

For better looking code:

```
const url = 'http://www.tppcrpg.net/rarity.html';
tabletojson.convertUrl(url)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data[0]);
  })
  .catch((err) => { 
     console.log('err', err);
   }); // to catch error
```

Comment: cheerio and https://github.com/misterparser/cheerio-tableparser worked for me